# How to use Pytest to assert multiple values

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, boto3

I'm new to pytest and unit tests. How to use assert with multiple values?
My function `get_private_subnet_ids():` returns multiple subnets in the form of a list. And my test function `test_sharing_private_subnets_exist(accountid)` should do an assert to check if they contain these subnets

How do I extract individual element of the list `private_subnet_ids` and compare each element with my defined `expected_subnets` list in test function?

I would like to have table-driven testing. I have a list to store all the test cases.
Below is the function that returns multiple subnets from AWS VPC matching the Tag `my-private`

```
def get_private_subnet_ids():
    private_subnet_ids = []
    vpc_client = aws_assumed_session_client(account_id=accountid, aws_service='ec2')
    subnets = vpc_client.describe_subnets()
    for subnet in subnets['Subnets']:
        if 'Tags' in subnet:
            for tag in subnet['Tags']:
                if tag['Key'] == 'Name' and tag['Value'].startswith('my-private'):
                    private_subnet_ids = subnet['SubnetId']
                    print("[DEBUG]Queried Public Subnet ID's: {}".format(private_subnet_ids))
    return private_subnet_ids
```

I want to have a test function like this using table driven testing, that tests if the subnets exist as defined in the `expected_subnets` list/table

```
def test_sharing_subnets _exist(account_id):
""" Tests to verify if Subnets exist in target account. This is example of table driven tests """
# subnets = ["my-private-1", "my-private-2", "my-private-3"]
expected_subnets = [ "subnet-0b6aaaf1ce07xx03", "subnet-0e54fda8f811fxxd8"," subnet-08f6d70b65a5cxx38"]
for subnet in expected_subnets:
    assert get_private_subnet_ids(subnet), "Subnet {} does not exist".format(subnet)
```

I run my pytest like this with the --accountids

```
pytest test_vpc_subnets.py --accountids 75381674129
```

Assertion Error

```
  AssertionError
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG]Queried Private Subnet ID's: subnet-08f6d70b65a5cxx38
[DEBUG]Queried PrivateSubnet ID's: subnet-0b6aaaf1ce07xx03
[DEBUG]Queried Private Subnet ID's: subnet-0e54fda8f811fxxd8
======================================================================================================= short test summary info =======================================================================================================
FAILED test_vpc_subnets.py::test_sharing_subnets_exist[753816747583-subnet-08f6d70b65a5cxx38] - AssertionError: assert 'subnet-08f6d70b65a5cxx38' in 'subnet-0e54fda8f811fxxd8'
FAILED test_vpc_subnets.py::test_sharing_subnets_exist[753816747583-subnet-0b6aaaf1ce07xx03] - AssertionError: assert 'subnet-0b6aaaf1ce07xx03' in ' subnet-0e54fda8f811fxxd8'
```

Comment: In pytest, you can use [parametrized tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html) for this, e.g. `@pytest.mark.parametrize("subnet_id", get_private_subnet_ids())`.

Comment: I'm confused: what do you mean by "assert to check if they contain these subnets _in their account_"? What do accounts have to do with subnets? In any case, you can `assert` anything you want in a Pytest test. `assert foo in [1, 2, 3]`, `assert foo == [1, 2, 3]`, `assert set(foo) = {1, 2, 3}`, ...

Comment: And MrBean's comment is correct: once you get the hang of regular tests, parametrizing them is the idiomatic way to run the same test against multiple values.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. The problem I'm facing is that the `private_subnet_ids` return multiple values. And I'm having a hard time to assert each elements(items) of the list. How do I extract element of the list `private_subnet_ids` and compare each element with my defined expected subnets list in test function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pytest, you can use [parametrized tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html) for this, e.g. you provide a list of parameters to the test, and the test is executed with each of the parameters:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("subnet", ["subnet-08f6d70b65b5xxxx",
                                    "subnet-0b6aaaf1ce207xxxx", 
                                    "subnet-0e54fda8f811ffxxx"])
def test_sharing_subnets_exist(subnet):
    assert subnet in get_private_subnet_ids()
```

If running `pytest -vv` on the test you get something like:

```
...
collecting ... collected 3 items

test_subnet.py::test_sharing_subnets_exist[subnet-08f6d70b65b5xxxx] PASSED                             [ 33%]
test_subnet.py::test_sharing_subnets_exist[subnet-0b6aaaf1ce207xxxx] PASSED                            [ 66%]
test_subnet.py::test_sharing_subnets_exist[subnet-0e54fda8f811ffxxx] PASSED                            [100%]

============================== 3 passed in 0.07s ==============================
```

I have ignored the `account_id` parameter, as it is not clear from the question what it shall do (this is ok as has been clarified in the comments), and the `subnet` argument in your test, as your function as shown is parameterless. I am assuming that you just want to test that each of the given IDs is contained in the output of the function `get_private_subnet_ids` (also has been verified in the comments)..

---

Note that there is an error in your function `get_private_subnet_ids` - instead of adding an ID to a list, you replace it. This line

```py
    private_subnet_ids = subnet['SubnetId']
```

should read:

```py
    private_subnet_ids.append(subnet['SubnetId'])
```

Comment: Thanks @MrBean Bremen. Yes, you are right. I want to test that each of the given IDs is contained in the output of the function get_private_subnet_ids.  I run my pytest like this with the accountid  `pytest test_vpc_subnets.py --accountids 75381674129`

Comment: get_private_subnet_ids returns a list of ID's as you see in the output of assertion error - Queried Public Subnet ID's:

Comment: For some reason, it only checks for `subnet-0e54fda8f811fxxd8` and not the rest. The function indeed returns a list of ID's

Comment: The issue lies with the function get_private_subnet_ids(), I printed the  private_subnet_ids bariable and it just prints `subnet-0e54fda8f811fxxd8` :(

Comment: Ok, I added a comment in the answer regarding your function. I hadn't looked at the implementation before.